# How to make image alternative text as required be more web accessibility?

Tags: media

In Drupal 7, how can I set image alternative text as required in "Body" field (CKEditor), "image" field and file upload by using "Media" module?

---- updated info for betherwisser on Aug. 20, 2014 @ 12:17pm
I know there is a file types section in Media but it is different from what you mentioned. However, It does not have the Alt text field option there. Please see screenshot for details.
[image]

ALSO, there is an option on image file for Alt Text but I'm not able to make that as required. See below screenshot.
[image]

Comment: That second screenshot is of the field setting for where you add the image, not for the field settings of fields *on* the image.

Comment: @betherwisser the first screenshot is the field on image but I dont see the Alt text option. :(

Comment: That doesn't look like an image, but I can't tell what file type it is because the file type name doesn't appear in the screenshot. Regardless, if you want a field that is not there yet, you can add it and use a view mode to control its display.

Comment: @betherwisser the file type on first screenshot is "image". There is no Alt Text field option as showed on first screenshot. I only can add text field and named as "Alt Text", but it would not be the real Alt Text.

Answer (score 4):

I found one of the solution by using [EIM](https://www.drupal.org/project/eim) module. I understand this is not the best solution but this module able to enable Alt field required on image field by content type.

---- updated info on Aug. 22nd 2014 @ 11:12pm
The EIM module adds checkboxes for the **fields of image** editing forms by content type. Including "**Alt field required**" and "**Title field required**". See below screenshot for details.

[image]

Comment: Hello. Could you include quick information about **how** this module answers your question? You know, in case of link going down, and to make search easier.

Comment: sorry, im going to edit my answer now

Comment: While this works with the default Drupal image widget, does not work with media browser widget.

Answer (score 3):

The media module should provide a field for entering alt, title, and descriptions for images. If you enter descriptive text in that field whenever you add an image, that should appear as the alt attribute when the content is rendered.

To modify attributes of the field, such at to make it required, edit the field definition:

[image]

Comment: I see the Media module provide field option on "Configuration > Media > File Types > Image > Manage Field", but I dont see the Alt field option. I also see the Alt field option on content type when adding image field, but how can I make it required?

Comment: You can make it required by managing the fields (structure/file-types/manage/image/fields) and changing the setting on the field.

Comment: On content type image field, it only allow me to enable the Alt field but does not have the option to make Alt field as required.

Comment: Added screenshot to answer.

Comment: I thought the File types you mentioned is content type. Now I see they are different. How you get the File type in Structure? Is it some kind of module?

Comment: I added screenshot on my post. The file type I have in media does not have the Alt text option.

Comment: I believe you are using a text field on that screenshot and named as "Alt Text". How can this function as real alt text inside the <img>?

Comment: I can confirm that that this does make alt text required across the site in the media module.

Comment: @chim I don't see the "File Type" under "Structure" that "beth" mentioned. The "alt text" screenshot from "beth" looks like a text field that named as "alt text", not the actual alt text inside the image field(http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_alt.asp).

Comment: The field field_file_image_alt_text is provided by the file_entity module which is a dependency of the media module.

Comment: Can you see anything at admin/structure/file-types

Comment: Possibly the module's changed since 2014