# How to fix millions of Alt Text are missing on body content?

Tags: nodes, media

This question is very similar to [my other question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/127169/how-to-make-image-alternative-text-as-required-be-more-web-accessibility). I have a website missing millions of **Alt Text** in **body content**(not image field). My solution is to set the default Alt Text as the file name without extension. Is it even possible, if so, how?

-- -- added additional info on Oct 2nd 12:40pm for tenken : below is a screenshot of setting

**PS: there is no replace setting on Setting section**

[image]

Here is the screenshot on setting section
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [Search and Replace Scanner](https://www.drupal.org/project/scanner) module to search through the text of your `body field`. You could use a regular expression to search for image tags without alt attributes.

Some excerpts from the module page:

> Features
>
> - Can search and replace text in CCK text fields, in addition to standard node title and body fields
> - Plain text search and replace regular expression search and replace
> - Case sensitive search option

This module is designed to work on MySQL and dedicated servers, be sure to review the module page and accompanying documentation.

Comment: I have not tried this yet, but will let you know once I did a sample.

Comment: This module does search and replace content or fields. For the Replacement, it does not has any option. I want to replace <img alt="" based on image file name without extension. Something like <img alt="image243" scr="/site/default/files/image243.jpg", <img alt="image412" scr="/site/default/files/image412.jpg"..... not <img alt="samename" scr="/site/default/files/image243.jpg", alt="samename" scr="/site/default/files/image412.jpg" :(

Comment: did you setup what fields you want to scan/replace with after installation? http://cgit.drupalcode.org/scanner/tree/INSTALL.txt?id=HEAD

Comment: I only see the setting for Scan(search), not the Replace. There only text field allow me to input for replacement. I'm going to update my post with screenshot. Please see above for details

Comment: ya i'm not 100% sure. I would suggest changing the search to `regular expression`. If needed I would also add a `text field` to all your nodes temporarily called `nid_text` and use views bulk operations to set it to the `Node ID` then include the `nid_text` in the Search fields try and do a replace using the regular expression and that new text field. Thats the best advice I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of offloading this type of regressive work to the client, meaning I would just write a Javascript function to do the work for me and let the user's browser do the work.  With jQuery, it is basically a one-liner.  Is there some part of your implementation that would not work with this solution?  The upside is that you wouldn't have to worry about tinkering with the database at all.